# Copy User Input file type to somewhere in Installation Directory using Izpack

Tags: java, izpack

I have created a Installer using IZpack.

Now we have a requirement to get some files as User inputs and put somewhere in Installation directory.

I have search a lot in internet but no clue how to process the file type user input to copy in installation directory at installation time.

I really appreciate, If somebody have done similar stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Custom Actions](http://izpack.org/documentation/custom-actions.html) feature of the IZPack, it allows to run arbitrary pre-packaged Java code during installation. You will be able to pop your own input dialogs, get the user input and copy where required.